# Is there a way to move an iframe scrollbar of a PDF from JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Im trying to visualize some PDF's from an Smart TV, so I'm going to use some invisible buttons to scroll up and down the document.

All of this, must be in web, this is what i tried:

JS:

```
<script> 
function scrollUp(){
    alert("funcion llamada UP");
    window.scrollBy(0, -50);
}
function scrollDown(){
    alert("funcion llamada DOWN");
    document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.scrollTo(10000,1000);
    window.getElementById('frame').scrollTo(50000, 20);
    //document.getElementById('frame').scrollTop = 438;
    //window.scrollBy(0, 50);
}

window.onload=inicio;   
function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#boton").onclick=scrollUp;
    document.querySelector("#boton1").onclick=scrollDown;
}
```

PHP + HTML:

```
echo "<iframe src='$fichGG ' id='frame' class='frame' width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";
```

Alerts are working but all the options of getElement or scrollBy not working idk why.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for..... `document.getElementById('div_iframe').scrollTop = 500`
The 500 is how much pixels you scroll down by, and yes, this is JS.

Comment: Hi CodeMaster, thanks for your reply, I tried and it's not working, I'll have to look for another think.